# Multiplying a list in python --- deletes list

Tags: python-3.x, list, multiplication

I was attempting to multiply a simple list in python by -1 and got an empty list back.
Anyone know why?

I found how I want to do this using a lambda function, but I still need clarity.

```
L = list(range(10))
L = L * -1
```

The output was:  `[]`

I was expecting: `[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9]`

Comment: You might want to use [`np.array`](https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/operations.html). This could be done as `a = np.arange(10); a *= -1` or in one step as `a = -np.arange(10)`.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve can be done by using *list comprehensions* -

```
L = [-1*x for x in L]
```

OR - shorten it to (as @wjandrea suggested in the comment below):

```
L = [-x for x in L]
```

When you *multiply* a list with an integer as you are attempting - you create a repeated list

```
L = [1]
L = L*3 #Returns [1, 1, 1]
```

If you multiply with a negative number or 0 - you will get an empty list

Comment: You could save two chars by using unary minus: `[-x for x in L]`